# IFNULL function in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, ifnull

I'm trying to create a calculated field in Tableau - but for the below it says am missing an operator, how would it be?

```
IFNULL([Translator], [Translation Requestor 1])
THEN "NULL" 
ELSE "Not NULL" 
END
```

Comment: In simple English, what do you intend this formula to do?

Comment: The IFNULL function in Tableau checks the value of the first argument and returns it is it isn't null; if it IS null the second value is returned (you can check this in the live help available when creating the function). So all the THEN, ELSE END after it is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
IFNULL([Translator], [Translation Requestor 1])

Comment: Or you could use case when, not sure what the expected output is.